# Flyway not finding SQL migrations on Apache Karaf

Tags: osgi, flyway, apache-karaf

We are deploying our application in Karaf, and trying to use Flyway to handle the db migrations, but it is not finding our `V#__*.sql` files at runtime. Things I have checked:

- The jar file contains the sql files in the `db/migration` of the jar
- Changing the name of the folder you will get the Runtime Exception:

  ```
  Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: 
  Unable to scan for SQL migrations in location: classpath:db/migration
  ```
- When I turned on debugging for Flyway I can see it finds the folder on the classpath, but no files in it.

  ```
  DEBUG|org.flywaydb.core.Flyway|408-org.flywaydb.core-3.2.1|DDL Transactions Supported: true
  DEBUG|org.flywaydb.core.Flyway|408-org.flywaydb.core-3.2.1|Schema: my_database
  DEBUG|org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.scanner.classpath.ClassPathScanner|408-org.flywaydb.core-3.2.1|Scanning for classpath resources at 'db/migration' (Prefix: '', Suffix: '.sql')
  DEBUG|org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.scanner.classpath.ClassPathScanner|408-org.flywaydb.core-3.2.1|Scanning URL: bundle://418.0:1/db/migration
  DEBUG|org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.FeatureDetector|408-org.flywaydb.core-3.2.1|JBoss VFS v2 available: false
  DEBUG|org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.FeatureDetector|408-org.flywaydb.core-3.2.1|JBoss VFS v3 available: false
  DEBUG|org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.FeatureDetector|408-org.flywaydb.core-3.2.1|OSGi framework available: true
  DEBUG|org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.FeatureDetector|408-org.flywaydb.core-3.2.1|Spring Jdbc available: false
  DEBUG|org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbValidate|408-org.flywaydb.core-3.2.1|Validating migrations ...
  DEBUG|org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.scanner.classpath.ClassPathScanner|408-org.flywaydb.core-3.2.1|Scanning for classpath resources at 'db/migration' (Prefix: 'V', Suffix: '.sql')
  DEBUG|org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.scanner.classpath.ClassPathScanner|408-org.flywaydb.core-3.2.1|Scanning URL: bundle://418.0:1/db/migration
  DEBUG|org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.FeatureDetector|408-org.flywaydb.core-3.2.1|JBoss VFS v2 available: false
  DEBUG|org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.FeatureDetector|408-org.flywaydb.core-3.2.1|JBoss VFS v3 available: false
  DEBUG|org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.FeatureDetector|408-org.flywaydb.core-3.2.1|OSGi framework available: true
  DEBUG|org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.scanner.classpath.ClassPathScanner|408-org.flywaydb.core-3.2.1|Scanning for classes at 'db/migration' (Implementing: 'org.flywaydb.core.api.migration.jdbc.JdbcMigration')
  DEBUG|org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.scanner.classpath.ClassPathScanner|408-org.flywaydb.core-3.2.1|Scanning URL: bundle://418.0:1/db/migration
  DEBUG|org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.FeatureDetector|408-org.flywaydb.core-3.2.1|JBoss VFS v2 available: false
  DEBUG|org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.FeatureDetector|408-org.flywaydb.core-3.2.1|JBoss VFS v3 available: false
  DEBUG|org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.FeatureDetector|408-org.flywaydb.core-3.2.1|OSGi framework available: true
  INFO|org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbValidate|408-org.flywaydb.core-3.2.1|Validated 0 migrations (execution time 00:00.010s)
  DEBUG|org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbSchemas|408-org.flywaydb.core-3.2.1|Schema "my_database" already exists. Skipping schema creation.
  DEBUG|org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.Table|408-org.flywaydb.core-3.2.1|Locking table "my_database"."schema_version"...
  DEBUG|org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.Table|408-org.flywaydb.core-3.2.1|Lock acquired for table "my_database"."schema_version"
  INFO|org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate|408-org.flywaydb.core-3.2.1|Current version of schema "my_database": << Empty Schema >>
  INFO|org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate|408-org.flywaydb.core-3.2.1|Schema "my_database" is up to date. No migration necessary.
  ```
- The log shows that it is looking in the correct bundle as the 408 matches the installed bundle.

I am not sure what else to look for, as there are no errors logged, and it seems to be finding the folder where it should be, just not the sql files. I am assuming this is an manifest type issue, but I am not sure what to look for. What are the next steps?

Comment: Are you sure the files in question are actually added to the jar. If you build your bundle with the maven-bundle-plugin you might need to configure it appropriately.

Comment: Yes, I double checked that by extracting the jar and they are they in the DB migration path.

Comment: In that case try to debug to the point where the resources are loaded. You might need to patch that part to load the resources in an OSGi friendly way.

Comment: Yeah, that is where I am at currently. I am reading through the flyway docs so i can build it and add some debugging to figure out where it is actually going wrong. I am starting to wonder if it is loading the correct classpath scanner in my situation.

Comment: In that case make sure you'll use Bundle.getResource() to load the resource.

Comment: Jacob, how have you loaded Flyway into the OSGi container?  A wrapped bundle, embedded or at the System class loader level?

Comment: I deployed flyway into the osgi container itself, so as to not have to wrap it with my bundle. I'm new to osgi so I think I said that right.

Answer (score 0):

OSGi and classpath scanning is a tricky thing that seems to work differently in every container. Please file an issue in the issue tracker. Pull request also welcome.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Axel. I will open an issue in a bit, after I have debugged a little more. I don't want to waste anyones time to much if it is just something I am missing, sense I am fairly new to the entire OSGI concept.

Answer (score 0):

It likely depends on it how you've bundled Flyway.

If you've embedded it in the same bundle as your migration scripts it should just work.

If however, you have flyway as a standalone bundle, you'll need to let it know which classloader contains the resources.

One technique for this is to do the following from a class in the bundle which contains your migration resources.

```java
ClassLoader context = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();

try {
    Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(this.getClass());

    Flyway flyway = new Flyway();
    flyway.setDataSource("jdbc:h2:file:target/foobar", "sa", null);
    flyway.clean();
    flyway.migrate();
}
finally {
    Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(context);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by deploying a fragment bundle, and the Fragment-Host is set to org.flywaydb.core.  Take a look at the working example I put together at https://github.com/barryku/karaf-flyway-demo.  The example was inspired by the project at https://github.com/FlavioF/fabric8-osgi-flyway-example/tree/master/fabric8-osgi-flyway.